# Invalid / Unmodifiable / Unsupported DB Parameter: time_zone gives cloud-formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, troposphere

I tried to add a DBClusterParameterGroup to aurora postgresql engine. For that I used below command.

```
db_cluster_params = self.add_resource(
        rds.DBClusterParameterGroup(
            "CustomAuroraRDSClusterParamGroup",
            Description="Aurora RDS Cluster Parameter Group",
            Family="aurora-postgresql13",
            Parameters={
                "time_zone": "UTC"
            }
            
        )
    )
```

When I executed the above, I got the below error.

```
Invalid / Unmodifiable / Unsupported DB Parameter: time_zone
```

But based on [1] time_zone is a valid parameter. Could you please tell me what is the issue in my script?

[1] https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbclusterparametergroup.html

Answer (score 2):

Before applying parameters to a given **Family** of a **DBClusterParameterGroup**, we need to check the available parameters for that family.

You can use the below query for that.

```
aws rds describe-db-cluster-parameters --db-cluster-parameter-group-name default.aurora-postgresql13
```

based on the output of the above troposphere code should be changed like this.

```
db_cluster_params = self.add_resource(
        rds.DBClusterParameterGroup(
            "CustomAuroraRDSClusterParamGroup{}".format(identifier),
            Description="Aurora RDS Cluster Parameter Group",
            Family="aurora-postgresql13",
            Parameters={
                "timezone": "UTC"
            }
            
        )
    )
```